# Issue while deploying laravel-echo-server on linode.com

Tags: socket.io, laravel-5.5

I am following **[this article](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)** to implement socket.io for real time updates in Laravel 5.5. I have successfully implemented it.

I also deployed the code on linode.com, Everything works there but not sure how should I initialize and start laravel-echo-server there.

Can somebody please suggest?

> 2018-02-01 17:48:02,392 INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:03,393 INFO
>   success: laravel-queue-listener entered RUNNING state, process has
>   stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs) 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:03,394
>   INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:05,396 INFO
>   spawnerr: can't find command '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server'
>   
> 2018-02-01 17:48:08,401 INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:08,401 INFO
>   gave up: laravel-worker entered FATAL state, too many start retries
>   too quickly

**Command Details**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
command=/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

Comment: As much as I sympathise with you having a problem, you should really know better than to ask this on SO with over 2000 points. May I suggest the Laracasts forums or Reddit?

Comment: Those forums are not free to discuss problems, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, they are. Reddit has always been free, and though the Laracasts videos cost money, the forums do not. Both are excellent places to ask questions - for free.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `laravel-echo-server` installed

I would suggest installing a process manager, like supervisor:

`apt-get install supervisor`

You would then want to create a configuration file for your process, something like the below:

```
[program:laravel-socket]
process_name=%(program_name)s
directory=/your/site/directory
command=laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=YOURUSER
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/location/of/log/file
```

This will allow your process to run and restart automatically should it fail. A log file will also be created so you can manage the output of the process.

More information can be found on this here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

And in the Laravel documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: What errors are you getting in the supervisor logs?

Comment: which command doesn't work? You will need to be specific about what exactly you are doing